# Logical Argument: Removing Rows according to multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple columns. I want to take out rows from the set which meet two conditions.

I thought this would work:

CarS <- CarS[ CarS$CylCode !=17 && CarS$ECode !=191,]

But this is taking out all rows that meet either condition, and I want both conditions to be met in order for that row to be removed?

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is something else going on because `mtcars[mtcars$vs != 0 & mtcars$am != 0, ]` gives me the expected results, ie, all rows in which both columns are not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using sqldf, although this will not be the the most elegant answer:

```
library("sqldf")

CarS<-sqldf('
   select *
   from CarS
   where
      (CylCode <> 17 and
       ECode <> 191 )
  ')
```

Second approach

```
CarS[setdiff(rownames(CarS),rownames(toremove )),]

toremove <-sqldf('
    select *
    from CarS
        where CylCode = 17 and ECode = 191 ')
```

Comment: Hmm.. This did the same thing as CarS <- CarS[ CarS$CylCode !=17 & CarS$ECode !=191,]     Your method removed all Cars with CylCode 17, even though I want to keep CylCode 17 for all instances which ECode is not 191. Any thoughts on adjustment? Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand the intent at first, it might be more straightforward to first identify the records you would like to remove, then create a new table removing these records.  
 <See edits above>